# Objective-C ignore \n newline in uvdm\niko5280

Tags: objective-c, newline

i am developing an app in objective C that's using the username uvdm\niko5280 and i its in the url `https://uvdm\niko5280:password@url` and it doesn't work  because its becoming:

this is my code

```
 NSLog(@"date: %@", [self getDataFrom:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://uvdm\niko5280:password@url"]]);
```

and the output is:

```
"https://uvdm
iko5280:password@url"
```

i dont know what to do, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a double backslash like **this**:

```
"https://uvdm\\niko5280:password@url"
```

The second backslash causes the first backslash to not be recognized as a command while still only inserting one backslash into the `String`.